# How to extract a digit from number in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

please help with query how to extract digit '1' from below table using SQL in oracle.

| Table |
| --- |
| 1000 |
| 1001 |
| 1010 |
| 0100 |

expected result ;

| Table |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 11 |
| 11 |
| 1 |

Comment: what is your expected result? 1-11-11-1? or 1-1-1-1? or..?

Comment: Following from what Vvdl said - can you share your current queries and the output from these please in a [mre]?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you are giving us a simplified version of your problem? One way to achieve this is is using `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace all characters but the character `1` with an empty space:

```
SELECT
   REGEXP_REPLACE(YOUR_COLUMN,'[^1]','') AS DESIRED_RESULT
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

You can check out this example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6baed7e404e2174f9b4818859b4c6e36)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the simple string function `TRANSLATE` (which is faster than regular expressions):

```sql
SELECT TRANSLATE(value, '10', '1') AS result
FROM   table_name
```

If you have more than binary digits then:

```sql
SELECT TRANSLATE(value, '1023456789.', '1') AS result
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '1000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1001' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1010' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '0100' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | RESULT |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 11 |
> | 11 |
> | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5046c2aed6093af10740652ed6bccab4)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp_replace:

```
WITH dat AS
(
SELECT '1000' AS numb FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '1001' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '1010' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '0100' FROM dual
)
SELECT regexp_replace(numb,'[^1]','')
  FROM dat;
```